# Resources - Javascript file strange behavior

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, resources, web

I'm having a problem regarding with my javascript files in my spring web project.

I wonder what's wrong with this, but my external javascript file doesn't reflect the changes I made to it when I run the program.
What I do is I need to rename the file so that the changes would take effect.

When I close eclipse and open it again, then the changes would not be reflect again. Then I need to rename the javascript file again.

It seemed that it retains the previous code it has everytime I close and open my eclipse.

I also tried to delete the javascrip file, and boom!!! it still run the previous code even though I already deleted it!!!

I'm lost guys, have you experienced this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the Spring Framework and the problem is not even in you code. The problem is in your IDE.

Try to reinstall it.